# How can I read .csv file and insert the record into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am looking for PHP script that capable of imports my 3 column data into my table which has 5 fields.

Is this possible?

Comment: try using this function fgetcsv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like this

```
$file = fopen("airport 123.csv","r ");
$i = 0;
while(!feof($file))
  {
    $file_data = fgetcsv($file);
    //print_r($file_data);
    $select = "select count(*) from airport_pricing";
    $result = mysql_num_rows($select);
    if($result>0)
    {
        echo $sql = "UPDATE airport_pricing SET pickup ='$file_data[0]',dropoff='$file_data[1]', price='$file_data[2]' ";
    }
    else{
        echo $sql = "INSERT INTO airport_pricing values(NUll,'$file_data[0]','$file_data[1]','$file_data[2]',1)";
    }
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    if(!$query)
    {
        $error = "Record is not inserted !";
    }
    else
    {
        $error = "Record is inserted Successfully !";
    }
    echo "<br />";
  }

fclose($file);

    echo $error;
```

?>

Comment: What's the reason behind the `SELECT COUNT()` query?

Comment: this is count and display the number of item in a field

Comment: But you are just counting if there is *any* entry in the table and not, if the current entry is already in the table. Furthermore, you do not check, if the result of the count is bigger than zero, but just, if there is any count returned. This should be true for any table, hence I doubt, this script will insert any entry at all. The only thing working here is traversing the CSV file.

Comment: Yes, exactly, but if you need you can apply checks also